# RequireJS optimizer with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs

I'm running on severals issues when I'm trying to run the node RequireJS on my project.

This is my folder structure :

```
-root
    -/src
        -App.coffee

    -/static
        -/vendor
            -/plugin
                -r.js
                -coffee-script.js

            -/lib
                -jquery.js

            -main.js

    -build.js
```

This is my build.js file :

```
({
    appDir          : './',
    baseUrl         : './static/js/',
    dir             : '../public',
    optimize        : 'uglify',
    exclude         : ['coffee-script'],
    stubModules     : ['cs'],

    paths: {

        // Libraries

        'modernizr'     : 'vendor/modernizr',
        'jquery'        : ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min', 'vendor/jquery'],
        'jqueryui'      : 'vendor/jquery-ui',
        'backbone'      : 'vendor/backbone',
        'underscore'    : 'vendor/underscore',

        // Plugins

        'plugin'        : 'plugin/plugin',

        // RequireJS

        'cs'            : 'plugin/cs',
        'coffee-script' : 'plugin/coffee-script'

    },
    shim: {

        'jqueryui' : ['jquery'],

        'underscore': {
            exports: '_'
        },

        'backbone': {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    modules: [{
        name: "main"
    }]
})
```

And finally this is my main.js file :

```
require({
  baseUrl   : '../../src/',
  paths: {
    cs: '../../cs',
    'coffee-script': '../../coffee-script'
  }
}, ['cs!App']);
```

I'm getting always error related to incorrect path setting and I can't figured out where I'm wrong.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The solution below worked in my case. It's a common issue with non-amd modules imported with shim or wrapped manually (for instance [this](https://github.com/pajtai/raphael-amd) one, with custom paths).

Try avoiding relative paths and use absolute <sup>1</sup> paths instead. 
A dependency called from an aliased module will use its current location to find the required module.

```
require.config(
{
  locale: window.GIS.i18n.locale,
  deps: ['cs!modules/main'],
  paths: {
    'i18n'                       : 'i18n',
    'underscore'                 : 'libs/underscore',
    'cs'                         : 'libs/cs', // there's no '../something/else/libs/cs'
    'CoffeeScript'               : 'libs/coffeescript', // ibidem.
    'text'                       : 'libs/text',
    // ... other amd module aliases go here...
  },

  shim:{
  // ...
  }

});

define(['cs!modules/main'], function(){});
```

<sup>1</sup> Of course, these are not absolute paths *per se*, but they are relative to the root of your module tree.